# How to send sms using node js and twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

How can I send a text message to a number with my company name and company logo with Twilio notify service in node js?
I am able to send messages but each time the sender is randomly generated numeric string like... 56161940 etc.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SMS delivery capabilities can vary by country. The company logo is not an option for SMS but an alphanumeric sender ID may be an option based on the country you are delivering the message to.

[Verified SMS](https://www.twilio.com/blog/verified-sms-helps-promote-trust) is something is early days that could, in the future, support company logo, to specific Android devices.

[Getting Started with Alphanumeric Sender ID for Twilio Programmable SMS](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Getting-Started-with-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Twilio-Programmable-SMS)